# Can anyone tell me why this isn't creating a square?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm following a tutorial to learn about canvas, and I'm unstuck pretty early on.

Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.lineJoin = "square";
context.strokeRect(10,10,200,200);
```

```css
#canvas{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: block;
 width: 900px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Canvas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 
 <body>

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

It seems like it should be pretty straight-forward, but it's not doing what I expect.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `height` and `width` of the canvas should initially be set in HTML or via DOM properties, not CSS to avoid resizing.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage):

> Indeed, the  element has only two attributes, `width` and
>   `height`. These are both optional and can also be set using DOM
>   properties. When no `width` and `height` attributes are specified, the
>   canvas will initially be 300 pixels wide and 150 pixels high. **The
>   element can be sized arbitrarily by CSS, but during rendering the
>   image is scaled to fit its layout size: if the CSS sizing doesn't
>   respect the ratio of the initial canvas, it will appear distorted.**

Because of this, your square was also being resized to the same size of the canvas and could no longer fit completely within it.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.lineJoin = "square";
context.strokeRect(10,10,200,200);
```

```css
#canvas{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="900"></canvas>
```